# Need help to group by then sort by value on an rdd at apache spark via scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I currently have the following format of data in an RDD:

```
("UserId, "TypeId", Score)
```

The typeId ranges from 1 to 57 for each user.

So the data looks like the following:

```
  RDD(
      ("user1", 1, 1.0),
      ("user1", 2, 2.0),
      ("user2", 1, 3.0),
      ("user2", 2, 4.0),
      ("user3", 1, 5.0),
      ("user3", 2, 6.0))
```

I will need to flatten this out to be:

```
("User1", 1.0, 2.0, ...),
("User2", 3.0, 4.0, ...),
("User3", 5.0, 6.0, ...)
```

Can anyone help me to point to the direction to tackle this?

Comment: I don't think tuples can have dynamic lengths.

Comment: what is the role of typeId here ? The final output just shows (users,listofsorted scores)

Comment: similar question : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40011756/sort-by-a-key-but-value-has-more-than-one-element-using-scala/40017314#40017314

Comment: Hi, I am trying to map typeId to be features.  So the final result is essentially user id follow by 57 features per each row.

Comment: Hi Knight71, thanx. I will check out that post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the RDD to `keyed RDD` , then use `groupByKey` on that RDD.

```
val sparkContext = new SparkContext("local", "Simple App")
  val ss = List(("user1", 1, 1.0), ("user1", 2, 2.0), ("user2", 1, 3.0), ("user2", 2, 4.0), ("user3", 1, 5.0), ("user3", 2, 6.0))
  val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(ss, 2)
  val keyedRDD = rdd map { s => (s._1, s._3) }
  val groupedRDD = keyedRDD.groupByKey()
  //val groupedRDD = keyedRDD.reduceByKey((x,y) => x+y)
  groupedRDD.foreach(record => {
    println(record)
  })
```

Comment: Hi Shankar, Thanx for the help.  I added a sortBy(_._2) before changing it into keyed RDD and that seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

I have combined the answers given by @(cpp Initiator) which is pure scala and shankar. You need to group by users and then sort the values in each group.

```
val data = Array(("user1", 1, 1.0),
      ("user1", 2, 2.0),
      ("user2", 1, 3.0),
      ("user2", 2, 4.0),
      ("user3", 1, 5.0),
      ("user3", 2, 6.0))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)

val userScoreRdd =rdd.map(x => (x._1,x._3))

//group and sort
userScoreRdd.groupByKey().mapValues(x => x.toList.sorted).collect

//Output
res1: Array[(String, List[Double])] = Array((user3,List(5.0, 6.0)), (user1,List(1.0, 2.0)), (user2,List(3.0, 4.0)))
```

Comment: Hi Knight71, thanx for helping out on this.  I would need to sort by typeId instead of just the third value.  This looks like you are sorting by the third value.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val ss = Seq( ("user1", 1, 1.0), ("user1", 2, 2.0), ("user2", 1, 3.0), ("user2", 2, 4.0), ("user3", 1, 5.0), ("user3", 2, 6.0))
ss: Seq[(String, Int, Double)] = List((user1,1,1.0), (user1,2,2.0), (user2,1,3.0), (user2,2,4.0), (user3,1,5.0), (user3,2,6.0))

scala> val a1 = ss map { s => (s._1, s._3) }
a1: Seq[(String, Double)] = List((user1,1.0), (user1,2.0), (user2,3.0), (user2,4.0), (user3,5.0), (user3,6.0))

scala> val a2 = a1.groupBy (_._1)
a2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Seq[(String, Double)]] = Map(user1 -> List((user1,1.0), (user1,2.0)), user3 -> List((user3,5.0), (user3,6.0)), user2 -> List((user2,3.0), (user2,4.0)))

scala> val a3 = a2 map { case(name, values) => val sortedValues = values.map(_._2).sorted
     | (name, sortedValues) }
a3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Seq[Double]] = Map(user1 -> List(1.0, 2.0), user3 -> List(5.0, 6.0), user2 -> List(3.0, 4.0))
```